# Run a exe file from QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I am trying to run an exe file from the python console in QGIS.

my_aplication.exe is a script made in Python3.4 and 'compiled' to windows exe file

```
import os
os.system('C:\Python34\my_application.exe')
```

exit_status = 1

But it does not works

How can I do that ?

Comment: it is running, but returning an exit code. You won't see any stdout/stderr messages this way. Have you tried running it standalone from cmd/Powershell to see what the error is? You might want to consider using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) library if you actually want to read the output of your exe.

Comment: import os
    import sys
    os.system(r'C:\Python34\my_application.exe' )                                      but only load a part of it. Neither icons, no pics loaded and the application only shows the main_window and the radio_buttons.